# Aplicacion reemplaza a otra completamente diferente ("actualización de esta aplicación existente")

Tags: ionic, cordova

Estoy trabajando con Ionic, genero dos aplicaciones:

```
ionic start app1
ionic start app2
```

Luego genero un APK de la primera:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Lo instalo satisfactoriamente en mi dispositivo, pero cuando genero el APK de la `app2` y quiero instalarlo en el celular, me arroja en pantalla que este es una actualización de `app1`, obligandome a eliminar la primera para poder instalar la segunda...

¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Cómo puedo tener dos aplicaciones generadas por Ionic conviviendo en el mismo dispositivo?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes chequear en el archivo config.xml que no tengan el mismo id:

```
<widget id="new.app.id" version="0.0.1" mlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Si tienen diferentes id debería permitirte instalar las dos aplicaciones.

Saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias! Resultó perfectamente!!